# HERE Waypoint Sequence API

Tags: here-api

Since yesterday 23/01/2019 I started getting the following error when using the HERE Waypoint Sequence API.

> Technical error while generating the response. Please contact TCS. Error ID: de4aae0d-da0c-4cfe-b23c-29eb9ede7dd7

I do not have anymore detail, as this is all the response gives me.
I am using the same app_id and app-code as always and this just started happening without warning.

I am using an ajax call using this url: **https://wse.cit.api.here.com/2/findsequence.json**

The issue is also intermittent and sometimes the response generates results and the other 90% it generates the error. I am at a loss as I cannot find anything on the Here API FAQ site.

Here is a code snippet of the ajax call:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://wse.cit.api.here.com/2/findsequence.json',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  jsonp: 'jsonCallback',
  data: request,
  success: function(response) {
    if (response.errors.length == 0) {
      //use response to build route order html
    } else {
      $('.packageError').append(response.errors[0]);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Sounds like there was a technical error with the API generating the response and you need to contact TCS...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, their TCS redirects me to Stack Overflow and either their support is down or I am not filling out the correct details as the submit button is not available and there are no errors stating what fields might be wrong. I am not looking for pricing options, just if their API changed, or if it is down, and I need to start looking elsewhere for a more reliable API.

Comment: In any case no one here will have any technical understanding of their API in order to help you. The code you've shown us appears fine at first glance. You need to speak to the provider directly.

Comment: Thanks anyway, they have no details regarding error codes on their documentation, and no other contact details apart from the form with a disabled submit button, which I had to go manually enable in the source after I filled out the form. My guess is they have no one looking at these requests.

Answer (score 0):

The HERE Waypoint Sequence API is using the Matrix Routing Service in the backround for calculating all the routes. The error message points to to a timeout from the Matrix Routing itself. In this case please resend the request. We will update the documentation concerning the error codes shortly.